# ASP.NET MVC Files names underscore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

There is a naming convention to use underscore prefix for views which are not accessed directly (partial view, layouts, etc.) in ASP.NET MVC razor. I am not sure whether I should to use this prefix for view which is accessed only from child action.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, you should not. As you said, prefixes are used by convention for views not accessed directly. But if child action has view, it means it IS accessed, so prefixing that view name with underscore would mean breaking another convention (more robust and conventional one :)) - naming views according to action names. So don't prefix them, or you will have to explicitly specify view name in child action.